# HtmlAgility Pack get single node get null value

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get a single node with an XPath, but i am getting a null value on the node, don' t know why

```
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string nodeValue;
        string htmlCode = wc.DownloadString("http://www.freeproxylists.net/fr/?c=&pt=&pr=&a%5B%5D=0&a%5B%5D=1&a%5B%5D=2&u=50");
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        html.LoadHtml(htmlCode);
        HtmlNode node = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='DataGrid']/tbody/tr[@class='Odd']/td/a");
        nodeValue = (node.InnerHtml);
```

Comment: There are three things I'd check: #1) that the response comes before a timeout kicks in (i.e. in debug can you see the htmlCode string set?) #2) if you want to use xpath, that the response is a well-formed xml (to me that page gives validation error), #3 if you select a single node, ensure that your xpath does not match more than one, which may well be if you use // at the start, so add also a [1] at the end to force return the first match only

Comment: Hey. I didn't spend time writing code for you to not have you respond.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 2 mistakes in your xpath compared to the html you're trying to get information from.

1. There are no <a> that has <tr class=Odd"> as an ancestor.
2. Even if your Xpath had worked then you would only have gotten one <td> since you have decided to SelectSingleNode instead of SelectNodes

It looks like the are doing some kind of lazy protection from what you're trying to do. Since the a-tag is just represented in hexadecimal enclosed in IPDecode. So really it is no problem to extract the link. But the least you could have done was to look at the html before posting. You clearly have not tried at all. Since the html you're getting from your current code is not the <body> of the link you gave us - meaning you have to get the htmlpage from the absolute url or just use Selenium.

But since I am such a swell guy I will make your entire solution for you using **Xpath, Html Agility Pack and Selenium**. The following solutions gets the html of the site. then reads only the <tr> that has class="Odd". After that it finds all the "encrypted" <a> and decodes them into a string and writes them into an array. After that there is a small example of how to get an attribute value from one anchor.

```
    private void HtmlParser(string url)
    {
        HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags=true;

        GetHTML(url);
        htmlDoc.Load("x.html", Encoding.ASCII, true);      

        HtmlNodeCollection nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='DataGrid']/descendant::*/tr[@class='Odd']/td/script");
        List<string> urls = new List<string>();

        foreach(HtmlNode x in nodes)
        {
            urls.Add(ConvertStringToUrl(x.InnerText));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(ReadingTheAnchor(urls[0]));
    }

    private string ConvertStringToUrl(string octUrl)
    {

        octUrl = octUrl.Replace("IPDecode(\"", "");
        octUrl = octUrl.Remove(octUrl.Length -2);
        octUrl = octUrl.Replace("%", "");
        string ascii = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < octUrl.Length; i += 2)
        {
            String hs = string.Empty;

            hs   = octUrl.Substring(i,2);
            uint decval =   System.Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16);
            char character = System.Convert.ToChar(decval);
            ascii += character;

        }
        //Now you get the <a> containing the links. which all can be read as seperate html files containing just a <a>
        Console.WriteLine(ascii);
        return ascii;
    }

    private string ReadingTheAnchor(string anchor)
    {
        //returns url of anchor
        HtmlDocument anchorHtml = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        anchorHtml.LoadHtml(anchor);
        HtmlNode h = anchorHtml.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("a");
        return h.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
    }

    //using OpenQA.Selenium; using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
    private void GetHTML(string url)
    {
        using (var driver = new FirefoxDriver())
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
            Console.Clear();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("x.html", driver.PageSource);
        }
    }
```